# ios mapkit markers load their images in unpredictable way

Tags: ios, json, xcode, uiimage, mapkit

So, i am using native mapkit and load markers in json format.When i parse my json i have a special parameter, which detects what image should be used as icon(from images.xcassets) for current marker.But every time i load it, smth goes wrong and image assigns in unpredictable way and when i scroll map to new position and then back, markers again change their icons .Moreover, the same algorithm works fine on android using native sdk.I don't think the problem is in parse algorithm, but in map itself.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at reuse identifiers for annotation views. It sounds like you are reusing views when you don't want to be, thus the new image is never set.